# Is there any way of playing .amr audio file in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, audio, amr

I am trying to play .amr using  tag in react.js but this file is not playing. I read somewhere that html browser does not support .amr audio file is there any work around for this?

This is the code to my audio tag:

```
<audio controls className="my-3 border border-primary" preload="auto" style={{ borderRadius: "10rem" }}>
    <source src={audio_source} />
</audio>
```

Comment: Convert your file to `mp3`?

Comment: Any good way to convert amr to mp3 on runtime